# PHP Arrays - read from CSV file, make first column key, second column value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
first-key,first-value
second-key,second-value
third-key,third-value
fourth-key,fourth-value
```

I am reading these in to an array using:

```
$tmp_array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./values.csv'));
```

However, this results in this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first-key
            [1] => first-value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => second-key
            [1] => second-value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => third-key
            [1] => third-value
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => fourth-key
            [1] => fourth-value
        )

)
```

What I would like is this array:

```
Array
(
    [first-key] => first-value
    [second-key] => second-value
    [third-key] => third-value
    [fourth-key] => fourth-value
)
```

One way I can achieve this is by doing this:

```
$tmp_array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./values.csv'));
$array = [];
foreach ($tmp_array as $row) {
    $array[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps using `array_map()`?

Comment: I think it is more common to see CSV files where the top row is optionally headers, and each subsequent row are isolated field/columns. Your CSV isn't invalid but I think most examples out there assume otherwise. Because of that, *think your second way of doing it is probably best*. Are you absolutely certain that your second column will never contain a comma? If it ever could, you'd want to `join` the remaining columns in that row, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of better in this context. I think your solution is good enough. Is better:

- not using foreach?
- less lines?
- less variables?
- using more standard library functions?

I want to post 2 propositions:

```
// 1
$tmp = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
$data = array_combine(array_column($tmp, 0), array_column($tmp, 1));

var_dump($data);

// 2
$data = [];
array_walk(
  $tmp,
  function($e) use (&$data) {$data[$e[0]] = $e[1];}
);

var_dump($data);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["first-key"]=>
  string(11) "first-value"
  ["second-key"]=>
  string(12) "second-value"
  ["third-key"]=>
  string(11) "third-value"
  ["fourth-key"]=>
  string(12) "fourth-value"
}
array(4) {
  ["first-key"]=>
  string(11) "first-value"
  ["second-key"]=>
  string(12) "second-value"
  ["third-key"]=>
  string(11) "third-value"
  ["fourth-key"]=>
  string(12) "fourth-value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In regards to "better", I should have elaborated. I was hoping there was a one liner that doesn't involve using two different arrays (i.e. so CSV the file could be read directly in to an array).